# StatusBar text color doesn't change to Light Content

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios13, uinavigationbarappearance

There is an issue with the status bar text color in my app, it doesn't change when using

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
```

I want to specify the color of StatusBar text color for HomeViewController, I tried a lot but still the same problem.

I'm having custom **UINavigationBarAppearance** in this function I used:

```
extension HomeViewController: UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {
    func setupNavigationWithLargeTitle() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .customDarkGray()
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 14)
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .white
        searchController.isActive = true
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        self.title = "Home"
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, .font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Heavy", size: 36)!]
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .CustomGreen()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "star"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveButtonTapped))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(menuButtonTapped))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
    }
```

And I'm using SideMenu by jonkykong and this is the function I used:

```
func setupLeftSideMenu() {
        SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = leftMenuNavigationController
        leftMenuNavigationController.leftSide = true
        leftMenuNavigationController.statusBarEndAlpha = 0
        leftMenuNavigationController.presentationStyle = .viewSlideOut
        leftMenuNavigationController.allowPushOfSameClassTwice = false
        leftMenuNavigationController.menuWidth = view.frame.width * (3/4)
        leftMenuNavigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. can you explain more?